# Why doesn't adding these floats add up?

Tags: c++, windows, floating-point

I know that these floating point questions are probably the most asked question here at stack overflow, but I can't find something that looks like mine.  In windows (visual studio) compiled as 32 bit if I do:

```
double lnA = 1448481410.0;
double lnB = 0.75599998235702515;
double lnC = lnA + lnB;
```

I get lnC = 1448481408.0000000.  I can understand a small difference because of the floating point representation, but I don't understand why lnA - lnC == 2?

UPDATED: 
So here is the actual output using Visual Studio 2010:  This is a MFC application which is why I am using TRACE.

```
double lnA = 1448481410.0;
double lnB = 0.75599998235702515;
double lnC = lnA + lnB;

TRACE("A = %f B = %f C = %f A - C = %f\n",lnA, lnB, lnC, lnA - lnC);
```

A = 1448481410.000000 B = 0.756000 C = 1448481408.000000 A - C = 2.000000

UPDATE2: In trying to make a minimal complete example such as below, I do not see the same problem.  Only when it is part of my large application.  Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double lnA = 1448481410.0;
    double lnB = 0.75599998235702515;
    double lnC = lnA + lnB;

    std::cout << "A: " << lnA << "B: " << lnB  << "C: " << "Diff: " << lnA - lnC << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: put your complete code please

Comment: Post a [MCVE] that reproduces the behaviour you're concerned of.

Comment: [lnA - lnC is -0.756, not 2](http://cpp.sh/2l3z).

Comment: What is `lnA - lnC == 2`? You use it in a `if`?

Comment: These questions need to be accompanied with information on *how* you're determining the value is `2`.  Maybe your output statement is wrong (`printf` with wrong format specifier, for example), maybe you're converting / casting incorrectly somewhere, maybe your debugger is off, etc  Just posting 3 lines of valid declarations and calculations doesn't give this information.

Comment: moreover the value of lnC is correct if u use `float` instead of `double` but `lnC-lnA != 2`

Comment: We need a COMPLETE program, that produces this exact result. My suspicion is that you have been mixing what you post here and an implementation using `float` instead of `double` - at least, that will reproduce exactly the results you are seeing.

Comment: Double check that your "big application" is actually using `double`! (pun not intended!)

Comment: And watch for `#define double float` or similar.

Comment: If you can't find a `#define` that explains the problem, the next troubleshooting step is to make a copy of your application and start tearing bits out.  For example, does it happen if you call the function in question directly from main(), or only later on?  What if you leave out all the modules other than the one containing the code?  What if you copy the code *into* the main function?  It can take time, but you should eventually be able to narrow down a specific cause by process of elimination.

Comment: Oh, and it might conceivably be related to the compiler settings rather than the code itself.

Comment: There is a further possible explanation (but quite unlikely, IMO), and that is that the code is using x87 instructions, and somehow the FP control word has been set to "round to 32-bit" (either as a bug in the compiler or from some code in the overall project that is doing that)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I am away from work for the holiday, but I will check on Monday.  But I think this is the most correct answer.  This application uses Direct3d/Ogre and by searching for this term, it seems that the DirectX by default sets the FP control word to force everything to be floats.  Looks like if I pass D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE to DirectX it will leave this alone.

Comment: @CptanPanic: I added a reflection on FP control register values in my previous discussion on floating point values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some investigation, I have come to the conclusion that your code is PROBABLY confusing `float` and `double` (or viewing the output of code that is different from what you actually posted).

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double lnA = 1448481410.0;
    double lnB = 0.75599998235702515;
    double lnC = lnA + lnB;

    std::cout << std::fixed << "A:" << lnA << " B:" << lnB << " C:" << lnC << std::endl;
}
```

Produces:

```
$ ./a.out
A:1448481410.000000 B:0.756000 C:1448481410.756000
```

Now, as Soulsabr said in a comment, if we use `float` instead of `double`, the result is different:

Only these lines changed:

```
float lnA = 1448481410.0;
float lnB = 0.75599998235702515; 
float lnC = lnA + lnB;


$ ./a.out
A:1448481408.000000 B:0.756000 C:1448481408.000000
```

This is because the number of bits in a `float`, in typical systems, is 32 bits, which is split as 8 bits of exponent, one bit of sign, and 23 bits [plus one hidden] for the mantissa. so the value is `S * M * 2^E`, where `S` is the sign, `M` is the mantissa, and `E` is the exponent. The size of `M` is 23 bits, so it can be used to describe values up to about 8 Million precisely. We can shift the value using E, but no matter what value we pick, the smallest value that can change within the number is the next larger integer of x/8 million of the actual value. So 14 million becomes +/- 2 in the smallest value that "makes a difference". Adding 1 or less will have no effect at all.

The `double` code "works" because a 64-bit double has a 53-bit mantissa, which allows the value to be +/- 1/2^53 of the actual value, which is a MUCH bigger value, and allows for more precise calculaton. But take a big enough and small enough value, and we get the same problem if they are far enough apart. It's just a matter of how floating point values work. You only have so many bits. There are "big math" libraries that allow greater number of bits, ("infinite", subject to memory being available), but of course, with larger values, the calculation speed goes down, and for most things 1/2^53 of the value is "good enough".

Edit (based on comment by OP):

A similar effect to the "use float" can happen if, when using x87 instructions, the FPU is set to "round to 32 bits", which means that even though the calculation is made with 64-bit floating point values, the intermediate results are rounded to 32-bit precision. Per comment above, this seems to be a particular software product that does some "Magic" to achieve this, and there is a simple workaround.

Comment: It doesn't help him/her unless you explain why doubles work in the place of a float.

Comment: I don't see any information where `float` is used? [other than the generic term "floating point"]

Comment: And I said it wasn't an answer, so don't downvote it for that reason, please!

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I got my answers from two different issues crossed.  I apologize for that.

Comment: If it's not an answer you could edit it and make it a community wiki answer to avoid downvotes.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: I have "upgraded" my non-answer into at least a bit more explanation of what I think is happening. We still don't have a reproducible example from the OP, so it's still a bit of a guess as to what is going on.

Comment: Sorry for late response, but it turned out it was the x87 issue.  It turned out that ogre was setting round to 32bit flag in directX.